# Report wide filter contradicting visuals

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a flat excel file (all content in 1 file) that I'm using with powerBI along with report wide filters. I'm trying to get my head around this issue. In 1 visual I count the responses to a survey and use the location of each responder as the x Axis
That gives me this

> Chart 1

[image]

**Where as if I create a new chart and change the axis to the survey response value and colour by the location you can see there are responses recorded for these locations**

> Chart 2

[image: Location used to colour response count]

The really strange thing is that if I change the report wide filters to 1 particular value Chart 1 will work and so will Chart 2. `I can also copy and paste the "broken" chart to a new sheet in the same .pbix file and it starts displaying correctly.` 
I feel this is something very obvious I'm missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened but it was easier to create new pages and copy the "malfunctioning" charts to the new page. Once there they immediately starting charting properly